# Testing my linear model

Tags: linear-model, goodness-of-fit

I have used R to fit a linear model to some data. I have used 2 predictors one has 3 categories. What would be some suitable tests to see how well it fits the data

Comment: I'd suggest searching the site for goodness of fit tests.  There are bound to be many questions and some very good answers on this.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read about bias variance trade-off and cross validation techniques, I think 3rd and 5th chapter from this book http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ would be good starting points